# jmeter echo server test in tcp and beanshall solve

Tags: jmeter

> 2017-08-08 15:41:59,915 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: `import java.io.*; import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.*; import java.u . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Object constructor
>   2017-08-08 15:41:59,915 WARN o.a.j.m.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script. org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of:`import java.io.*; import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler.*; import java.u . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Object constructor

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqdzl.png)
I would like to test the server with jmeter from echo server. Once it was sent to the server, it was successful. But the class I use is only a number. How to get a sentence in the jmeter?? this is first question.
The second problem can be seen from the photograph. response message is ok but i have beanshall error in the code. How to fix that?

```
    `  
    package org.apache.jmeter.protocol.tcp.sampler;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;

    import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
    import org.apache.jorphan.util.JOrphanUtils;
    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


    public class LengthPrefixedBinaryTCPClientImpl extends 
    TCPClientDecorator {
    private static final Logger log = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(LengthPrefixedBinaryTCPClientImpl.class);

private final int lengthPrefixLen = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("tcp.binarylength.prefix.length", 2); 

public LengthPrefixedBinaryTCPClientImpl() {
    super(new BinaryTCPClientImpl());
    tcpClient.setEolByte(Byte.MAX_VALUE+1);
}
@Override
public void write(OutputStream os, String s)  throws IOException{
    os.write(intToByteArray(s.length()/2,lengthPrefixLen));
    if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
        log.debug("Wrote: " + s.length()/2 + " bytes");
    }
    this.tcpClient.write(os, s);        
}

@Override
public void write(OutputStream os, InputStream is) throws IOException {
    this.tcpClient.write(os, is);
}

@Override
public String read(InputStream is) throws ReadException{
    byte[] msg = new byte[0];
    int msgLen = 0;
    byte[] lengthBuffer = new byte[lengthPrefixLen];
    try {
        if (is.read(lengthBuffer, 0, lengthPrefixLen) == lengthPrefixLen) {
            msgLen = byteArrayToInt(lengthBuffer);
            msg = new byte[msgLen];
            int bytes = JOrphanUtils.read(is, msg, 0, msgLen);
            if (bytes < msgLen) {
                log.warn("Incomplete message read, expected: "+msgLen+" got: 
     "+bytes);
            }
        }

        String buffer = JOrphanUtils.baToHexString(msg);
        if(log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Read: " + msgLen + "\n" + buffer);
        }
        return buffer;
    } 
    catch(IOException e) {
        throw new ReadException("", e, JOrphanUtils.baToHexString(msg));
    }
}

/**
 * Not useful, as the byte is never used.
 * <p>
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public byte getEolByte() {
    return tcpClient.getEolByte();
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void setEolByte(int eolInt) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot set eomByte for prefixed 
    messages");
    }
    }`
```

Comment: Please add the full `text` of the error line